# Where is the Android emulator in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I have just double checked, run install to modify VS, and it showed the emulator as installed. To feel sure, I uninstalled it, and re-installed it, and the installer gave no indication of any problems. If I run the installer now, all the Android boxes, SDK etc. and emulator, are checked, that is, they are supposed to be installed.

Yet there is no Android emulator in the drop-down for browsers in the toolbar in VS. What is up with this?

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/you-can-now-acquire-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-on-its-own.aspx

Try looking at the link, i provided. i believe it will be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator won't be available in Visual Studio if you don't meet the system requirements listed here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx